# Aligning like rows in a character matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, character

I've got a character matrix with structure like the following:

```
dog    1   cow    9     mouse  7 
bird   10  tiger  1     gnu    2
tiger  3   deer   7     deer   27
skunk  2   rat    50    NA     NA
mouse  8   snake  3     NA     NA 
cow    7   NA     NA    NA     NA
sheep  21  NA     NA    NA     NA 
gnu    5   NA     NA    NA     NA
```

Imagine this to be a matrix of animals in locales, with data for each locale defined by successive pairs of columns. Some animals may be common between locales, but locales may also have unique animals. Ultimately I want to make a heatmap of this data, and thus need to reorder this matrix to have a structure in which there is one column for all types animals and successive columns corresponding to numbers in each locale:

```
dog    1    NA    NA 
tiger  3    1     NA 
skunk  2    NA    NA
mouse  8    NA    NA
cow    7    9     NA
sheep  21   NA    NA
gnu    5    NA    2
deer   NA   7     27
rat    NA   50    NA
snake  NA   3     NA
mouse  NA   NA    7
bird   10   NA    NA
```

In other words, I have

```
A1 <- c("dog", "bird", "tiger", "skunk", "mouse", "cow", "sheep", "gnu")
B1 <- as.character(c(1, 10, 3, 2, 8, 7, 21, 5))
A2 <- c("cow", "tiger", "deer", "rat", "snake", NA, NA, NA)
B2 <- as.character(c(9, 1, 7, 50, 3, NA, NA, NA))
A3 <- c("mouse", "gnu", "deer", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
B3 <- as.character(c(7, 2, 27, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
TheMatrix <- cbind(A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3)
```

and want

```
a1 <- c("dog", "tiger", "skunk", "mouse", "cow", "sheep", "gnu", "deer", "rat", "snake", "mouse", "bird")
b1 <- as.character(c(1, 3, 2, 8, 7, 21, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10))
b2 <- as.character(c(NA, 1, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, 7, 50, 3, NA, NA))
b3 <- as.character(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 27, NA, NA, 7, NA))
DesiredResult <- cbind(a1, b1, b2, b3)
```

Ideas on how to achieve this reorganization? It could done with loops and accounting, but surely there's a more elegant way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)

ncols = ncol(TheMatrix)
nrows = nrow(TheMatrix)

dcast(as.data.frame(na.omit(cbind(c(TheMatrix[,seq(1,ncols,2)]),
                                  c(TheMatrix[,seq(2,ncols,2)]),
                                  rep(colnames(TheMatrix)[seq(2,ncols,2)],
                                      each = nrows)))),
      V1 ~ V3, value.var = 'V2')
#      V1   B1   B2   B3
#1   bird   10 <NA> <NA>
#2    cow    7    9 <NA>
#3   deer <NA>    7   27
#4    dog    1 <NA> <NA>
#5    gnu    5 <NA>    2
#6  mouse    8 <NA>    7
#7    rat <NA>   50 <NA>
#8  sheep   21 <NA> <NA>
#9  skunk    2 <NA> <NA>
#10 snake <NA>    3 <NA>
#11 tiger    3    1 <NA>
```

There are a lot of things (that are each quite simple) happening here and to understand, just run each little bit on its own (starting from the inside and go out).

Comment: Thank you, I've never worked with reshape2, this does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take:

```
> x <- read.table(text = "
+ dog    1   cow    9     mouse  7 
+ bird   10  tiger  1     gnu    2
+ tiger  3   deer   7     deer   27
+ skunk  2   rat    50    NA     NA
+ mouse  8   snake  3     NA     NA 
+ cow    7   NA     NA    NA     NA
+ sheep  21  NA     NA    NA     NA 
+ gnu    5   NA     NA    NA     NA ")
```

A. Transform you source data into a list of data frames with 3 columns: animal, count and locale number:

```
> ll <- lapply(1:(ncol(x)/2), 
               function(i) cbind(x[c(2*i-1, 2*i)], data.frame(locale = i)))
[[1]]
     V1 V2 locale
1   dog  1      1
2  bird 10      1
3 tiger  3      1
4 skunk  2      1
5 mouse  8      1
6   cow  7      1
7 sheep 21      1
8   gnu  5      1

[[2]]
     V3 V4 locale
1   cow  9      2
2 tiger  1      2
3  deer  7      2
4   rat 50      2
5 snake  3      2
6  <NA> NA      2
7  <NA> NA      2
8  <NA> NA      2

[[3]]
     V5 V6 locale
1 mouse  7      3
2   gnu  2      3
3  deer 27      3
4  <NA> NA      3
5  <NA> NA      3
6  <NA> NA      3
7  <NA> NA      3
8  <NA> NA      3
```

B. `rbind` these data frames together. You should make names in all data frames equal first, otherwise `rbind` won't work:

```
> for (i in 1:(ncol(x)/2)) names(ll[[i]])[1:2] <- c("animal", "count")
> x <- Reduce(rbind, ll)
   animal count locale
1     dog     1      1
2    bird    10      1
3   tiger     3      1
4   skunk     2      1
5   mouse     8      1
6     cow     7      1
7   sheep    21      1
8     gnu     5      1
9     cow     9      2
10  tiger     1      2
11   deer     7      2
12    rat    50      2
13  snake     3      2
14   <NA>    NA      2
15   <NA>    NA      2
16   <NA>    NA      2
17  mouse     7      3
18    gnu     2      3
19   deer    27      3
20   <NA>    NA      3
21   <NA>    NA      3
22   <NA>    NA      3
23   <NA>    NA      3
24   <NA>    NA      3
```

C. Finally, use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package:

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(x, animal ~ locale, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "count")
   animal  1  2  3
1    bird 10  0  0
2     cow  7  9  0
3    deer  0  7 27
4     dog  1  0  0
5     gnu  5  0  2
6   mouse  8  0  7
7     rat  0 50  0
8   sheep 21  0  0
9   skunk  2  0  0
10  snake  0  3  0
11  tiger  3  1  0
12   <NA>  0 NA NA
```

D. Last step to clean up the output and replace `0` with `NA` is left as an exercise for the reader :).

Comment: Thank you, your comments are helpful. And I got the NAs removed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with `Reduce`

```
#provide number of locales
max_locale=3
#this list contains the column numbers we want to use to split TheMatrix
split_list=split(1:(2*max_locale),sort(rep(1:max_locale,2)))

#this function will be used to re-merge the split matrix
my_locale_merge=function(x,y) {
    merge(x,y,by.x=colnames(x)[1],by.y=colnames(y)[1],all=TRUE)
}

#the outer subset is used to get rid of the NA animals
subset(
    #reduce subsequently applies my_locale_merge to the split matrix
    Reduce(
        "my_locale_merge",
        #lapply is used to split the matrix
        lapply(split_list,function(x) {
            as.data.frame(TheMatrix[,x,drop=FALSE],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
            })
        ),
    !is.na(A1)
)
```

As far as I understand, `Reduce` does not allow the user to pass on additional function arguments like `by.x`. Therefore, I was defining a new function `my_locale_merge` that handles these arguments.